# mysql query difficulty with type

Tags: mysql

This makes no sense!
The update query only actually updates if the value is an INT (yes it is defined as text).
The INSERT which has the same variables works with type of value!

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `atuam_mae`.`missoes` SET  `mensagemdeuser` =  $message WHERE  `missoes`.`id` =$idmissao;");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `atuam_mae`.`concelhos` (`id` ,`tempo` ,`userid` ,`concelho`) VALUES (NULL , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , $user ,  '$message');");
```

Comment: You quote `$message` in one of the queries. Why don't you quote it in the other?

Comment: not sure why it was downvoted twice, not the most advanced question, but not worthy of downvoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are not enclosing your input variable in quotes:

```
"UPDATE  `atuam_mae`.`missoes`
 SET  `mensagemdeuser` =  '$message'
 WHERE  `missoes`.`id` = '$idmissao';"
```

**NB.** Don't do this and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) instead!

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE  `atuam_mae`.`missoes`
     SET  `mensagemdeuser` = :message
     WHERE  `missoes`.`id` = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(':message' => $message, ':id' => $idmissao));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `...='$message'` ?

Comment: @a1ex07: I'm not entirely sure, because I'm not able to guess what the column names try to say … but my prepared statement mitigates that alltogether :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you meant but try putting values (right of the =) between single quotes this way:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `atuam_mae`.`missoes` SET  `mensagemdeuser` =  '$message' WHERE  `missoes`.`id` ='$idmissao';");
```